# QT ts files merging

Tags: qt, translation

We have a Spanish .ts file, we need to add 20 strings from a separate Spanish translation file such that the secondary translation file will be merged with the primary during lupdate so that the resultant .qm file contains all the strings including the 20 new ones.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
lconvert -i primary.ts secondary.ts -o complete.ts
```